# Prevent multiple radio button selections across paginated jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a table which which has radio buttons In page 1 if I select one radio button and go to page 2 and select the other page the previous one is not overridden How to restrict only one radio button per entire datatable. So far I have tried this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778443/prevent-multiple-radio-button-selections-in-paginated-jquery-datatables
```

This doesn't seem to work .Need help!.

Here is the fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/testingcandy/6806m301/
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your radio buttons ,based on that try something like below , i hope it will work

```
$(document).on('click','.radioclass', function(){
    $('.radioclass').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

if not provide some demo

Comment: This didnt work I have provided the fiddle please have a look